# cakePHP afterFind and Association Values

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm using cakePHP 2.0 afterFind() callback to perform calculations on database values before it is displayed.

I have three models - Materials, Products and Quotes.

Each product has a material and calculations are performed in the Product afterFind callback using this association, specifically with the line:

```
$results[$key]['Product']['material_cost'] = $results[$key]['Product']['material_mass'] * $val['Material']['cost'];
```

with `$val['Material']['cost']` referring to the associated material.

All fine so far.

Next I have an afterFind() callback in my Quote model. The quote is associated with a product and the calculations in the quote model are dependant on the calculations in the Product model taking place - specifically the one which referances the material.

I can reference the Product model afterfind results in the Quote model afterFind just fine like: `$val['Product']['number_tools']`

However, now the Product model cannot find the associated material and I get the error:
Undefined index: Material [APP/Model/Product.php, line 126].
on line 126 of Product.php is

```
$val['Material']['cost']
```

How can I get around this problem, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: in general it is usually always a good idea to calculate that stuff "on demand" - shortly before actually outputting it. the main advantage is that those calculations won't be done if they are not needed, e.g. if a redirect occurs or if only title etc will be displayed in a view.

Comment: the calculations are needed more-or-less whenever the database is queried so the afterFind callback does exactly what I want and performs the calculations on the fly before the data is sent to the view. - Plus it allows me to keep all the logic in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the model for Material. The reason you can access it from the Product is because it is associated by relationship and your recursive is by default allowing the model to load the related data. So in the Quote model beforeFind method, before you start parsing through the data, load the Material Model:

```
public function afterFind($results) {

    App::uses('Material', 'Model');
    $material = new Material();
    $materials = $material->find(...);

    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        // access $materials['Material']['cost']
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chuck.  It makes sense except it is Product.php looking for the Material Model not Quote.php.  Quote php is associated with a product so is calling the Product model afterFind() function but throwing the error.  The Material Model is not accessed directly from Quote.php.  How would I get around this?

Comment: Could this be a bug? I've noticed if i try to load the Materials Model in the Product model with the above or ClassRegistry::init('Material')->find() or even $materials = $this->Material->findById(4); and then access it from the Quote model i get a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in

Comment: as a work around i've associated the Quote with the material and performed the calculations again in the Quote model, using an isset test to stop the Product model throwing the error.  However i'm on to another problem now which is probably best left for another question

Comment: The memory issue means you are pulling too many records for the amount of memory you have allocated.